# What is the meaning of trait `Member`?

Tags: pallet, runtime, substrate-node

Indeed, I don't understand this statement `A type that can be used in runtime structures` in docs: https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sp_runtime/traits/trait.Member.html

I noticed that some associated types in `Config` trait (like `Index`, `BlockNumber`, `Hash`,...) have defined `Member` trait, but the rest are not.

I have some questions:

1. When do we use `Member` trait?
2. What is the purpose of `Member` trait?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This trait seem to have been added [years ago](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/169/files#diff-43c34a92d71c44db120a557d303da49f38b3d97135298a18c7b7ad49f1b1ed67R282) and hasn't had much change ever since. I think the primary purpose is to simply be the super-trait number of other sub-traits and be used for any type that needs to be bounded by all the sub-traits.

You can and should use `Member` in any place where the set of sub-traits is what you already wanted to bound something by.